# Matching and cropping 2 slightly shifted photos of an object

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, correlation, affinetransform, image-registration

There's some 2D object that I have 2 photos of. I want to find their difference, but can't since they were captured with slight shift compared to each other.

Thus, each picture is almost identical to the other, but also each contains some information that the other one doesn't have (in the frame, because of the shift).

Using python, how do I align and crop them, so I'll be able to calculate the difference image?

Note: I realize that if the images are identical except for the shift then the difference should be 0 everywhere, but I'm expecting very small changes that I'll be trying to find with the difference image.

Demonstration here:

[image: Here]

Comment: use [RANSAC](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html)

Comment: Use FFT processing to do phase correlation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation

Comment: **show** us the real pictures... and then do some research on "image alignment/registration". it's a rule: [ask] -- your post doesn't even contain any code, yet you tag it "python". nor does it contain opencv code or specific issues with opencv.